# Como esse if será interpretado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if

Tenho uma função que executa diferentes ações na página de acordo com o callback passado para ela, estou usando `if` para verificar qual o callback chamado no `function('callback')` porém agora precisei fazer uma atualização na mesma e agora ela se encontra assim:

```
function Acoes(e){

   if(e == 1){...}
   if(e == 2){...}
   if(e == 3){...}
   if(e == 4 && foo == ""){...}else{...}  
}
```

- **a)** O que vai acontecer caso `e` seja igual a **3** e  `foo` não esteja
  vazia?
- **b)** O `if` correspondente ao `e == 3` será executado juntamente ao `else`
  do `if e == 4`?

Comment: Esses `if` interrompem a função? ou seja, há `return` dentro desses `if`?

Comment: Cada `if` manipula as propriedades css de algumas divs porem esse ultimo `if` depende da variável `var` para ser executado a mesma diz se o usuário está logado ou não, se ele não estiver a `var` fica vazia, mas e se o usuário estiver logado mudando `var` para algum valor, e o `if` for diferente de 4, o que acontece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em resposta às questões:

> **a):** caso `e` seja igual a `3` e a `foo` não esteja vazia

`if(e == 3){...}` dá `true` e executa, `if(e == 4 && foo == "")` dá false e vai executar o `else`.

> **b):** `e == 3` será executado juntamente ao `else` do if `e == 4`

Sim, no caso de `e` ter o valor `3`. E o `else` será executado independentemente do valor de `foo` uma vez que a primeira condição falha?

---

Se queres impedir que mais do que um corra de cada vêz podes usar `else if`. Assim tens um `if`, vários `else if` que são corridos só se o if e os `else if`  anteriores tiverem validado `false`, e por fim um `else` caso todos tenham validado `false`.

```
if(e == 1){...}
else if(e == 2){...}
else if(e == 3){...}
else if(e == 4){...}
else if (foo == "")
else{...}
```